# Truffle Plugin Verify Not Found in Global or Local node Modules

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am a back end engineer and currently going over Solidity course. While I am trying to use MythX for security analysis purpose, I need to run the command "**truffle run verify**" and found this error:

**Steps I took:**

1. Opened MythX account, generated an API Key and manually put it in ~/.bash_profile as
   **export MYTHX_API_KEY="eyJ...RjYWItOTEz ** and then restarted terminal.
2. I am on root folder of the following code base that has contracts, migration, and truffle-config.js https://github.com/ConsenSys-Academy/simple-coin
3. run **truffle compile** and then  **truffle run verify** and I ended up with the error below
4. Later I tried to remove the plugin by **npm uninstall truffle-plugin-verify** and re tryied, still same issue

**Spec:**

- MacOs Mojave 10.14.6
- npm: '6.14.8'}
- Truffle v5.1.45 (core: 5.1.45)
- Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
- Node v10.15.3
- Web3.js v1.2.1

FYI: I am using Mythx CLI https://mythx-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Error: truffle-plugin-verify listed as a plugin, but not found in global or local node modules!

```
at plugins.forEach.plugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/run/plugin.js:35:1)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at checkPluginModules (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/run/plugin.js:31:1)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/lodash/_createFlow.js:71:1
at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/run/plugin.js:70:1)
at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/run/index.js:29:1)
at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
at Object.module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/cli.js:56:1)
at __webpack_require__ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:1
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:89:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

the plugin is not found in node modules,
You need to Install the plugin with npm or yarn,
try:
"npm install -D truffle-plugin-verify".

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.

I need to use **mythx analyz** instead of **verify**.